# eclipse / GWT - how to include my own source from other projects?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am struggling with that for a while and google searches only confirmed that not all Java code can be used on GWT (due to not all being "recompilable" to JS via GWT), but **if I have the sources and use the "supported" piece of Java - I should be good to go**.

Here is what I tried.

**First**, I created a simple project with sources:

1. New->Java Project.
2. Single file in that project. Close to empty one actually:

here goes the dummy code I planted there:

```
public class Seven {
    public static String plusOne(){
        return "Eight";
    }
}
```

**Then**, when I try to include this into a GWT project using the following steps:

1. Starting from New->Web Application Project (deselecting App Engine and keeping "Generate project sample code")
2. Just modified a single line in the code

From:

```
nameField.setText("GWT User");
```

To:

```
nameField.setText(seven.Seven.plusOne());
```

All looks fine in Eclipse, but an attempt to compile (GWT Compile Project) results in either

an error message like that:

```
[ERROR] Line 44: No source code is available for type seven.Seven; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Unable to find type 'test3.client.Test3'
    [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
    [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

This is surely something easy - to point GWT to my source folder. But my search failed. Appreciate pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Yes! Yes! ... I found it.

You need to add an "inherit" in a GWT project (its XML file).

See here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWT/article.html#modules

Comment: GWT 101: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModules